# chart.js manage the height of the graph to match the data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

We are using chart.js to display the graph but there are more than 300 users in one place and when we are showing that in graph it look like as below:

[image]

I tried chart.js functionality but it doesn't seem to work:

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

Any help is deeply appreciated on this.

Comment: I don't think the height will ever grow unless the width and aspect ratio require this. You may need to set a height on the containing element yourself based on the number of series. (Additionally, not directly related, you can [tweak and filter legend display too](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/advent-of-code-charts/blob/34205a460df972a8754e4ec44817006f81a32eb5/src/js/app.js#L554-L562))

Answer (score 0):

We can acheive this by getting height of the page and mulitplying the barpercentage with no of the labels. It will get us percentage which we can convert to px with help of height and then set that height to parent container of canvas.

```
var h = $('body').height() * ((1 * data.labels.length)/100);
t.section.find("#"+target).parent().height(h)
```